# Displaying a div until list is populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of cards that gets populated by looping through a set of JSON data on a server. As you can imagine, this takes a little time, and I would like to display a small loading bar screen as the elements are loading.

I can use `document.ready` or `onload` functions of course, but the other elements on the page load almost instantaneously and I would like to display this `div` while the other elements are already loaded. Using `timeOut` of course is not accurate. It seems a possible solution is using `observeMutation()` but I am not sure how to implement it.

I have an else if statement, but its not working.

Update: Not using AJAX, using `snapshot()` from Firebase Real Time Server.

HTML:

```html
<!--ROUTINE CARDS-->
<!--THIS IS WHERE THE CARDS GET APPENDED-->
<ul id="cardList" class="cards">
</ul>

<!--LOADING SCREEN-->
<div id="loading">
  <h1>LOADING BAR OR SOMETHING</h1>
</div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```js
// Remove loading screen.
  checkList();

  function checkList()
  {
    if($(".card").is(":visible"))) // ".card" is the class of the elements that get appended to the ".cards" list.
    {
      $("#loading").hide();
    }
    else
    {
      setTimeout(checkList, 50);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you perform the `.hide()` as the last step of your success callback?

Comment: How are you loading these elements? Ajax of some kind?

Comment: Forgot to specify, not using ajax. Question updated.

Comment: Are you using a template engine or something ? Cause you could then simply add a conditionnal for displaying the loading or the list depending of server response. Could you edit and post your server side code ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using AJAX to load your cards, you should just load your initial state page with the loading and bind the hide method to your success callback.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your url",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $("#loading").hide();
  // Other stuff
});
```

Comment: Forgot to specify, not using ajax. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is spelling mistake in class. Use `.cards` instead of `.card`. Hope this will work.

Comment: ".card" is the class of elements that get appended to the ".cards" ul once snapshot is complete. Question updated.